# whats making this error? ill/formed special form let

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

When I run this , it says ill-formed special form let..
what could be the reason?

**Here is the code :**

```
(define (cm m)
(case m
(#\f) 
(do ((i 300 (+ i 100)))
((> i 1300))
(let ((x (* i 2))) (let ((y (/ x 2)) (z (+ x 3))))
(display x) (display " ")  (display y) (display " ") (display z) )))
((#\a) 'gold)
((#\c) 3)
(else 4)))
```

Comment: Proper indentation would help readability significantly here.

Comment: Get yourself an editor that can indent Scheme and show you where parentheses match.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We are happy to help, but can you please format your code properly? It's extremally unreadable, are you trying to make it hard for us?

Comment: Please correct indentation & most importantly - what are you trying to do?

Comment: I was just trying to have updated value for variables on every time the loop is executed. I think the error was mismatch of parenthesis. I got it fixed now. Thanks

Comment: @rsm hi, LOL, nooo. I am very new to this SO. Sorry for trouble. Actually the error was verz basic, i.e mismatch of parenthesis, got it fixed now.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, I just got emacs. I hope it would help in future. Thanks

Comment: @iota if you are not going to fix your question, and also answer is not important to you anymore, can you please delete your question? thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other commenters have stated, proper indentation will help significantly. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but this compiles and runs fine:

```
(define (cm m)
  (case m
    ((#\f) 
     (do ((i 300 (+ i 100)))
       ((> i 1300))
       (let ((x (* i 2)))
         (let ((y (/ x 2))
               (z (+ x 3)))
           (display x)
           (display " ")
           (display y)
           (display " ")
           (display z)))))
    ((#\a) 'gold)
    ((#\c) 3)
    (else 4)))

(cm #\f)
; 600 300 603800 400 8031000 500 10031200 600 12031400 700 14031600 800 16031800 900 18032000 1000 20032200 1100 22032400 1200 24032600 1300 2603

(cm #\a)
; 'gold
```